# Algorithm for estimating $\beta$ using a Taylor series expansion

Tags: calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion

I am working on the following question for a mathematical economics class.

> Consider an econometric model:
>   $$y_t=f(x_t,\beta) + e_t,t=1,...,T$$
>   where $\{ e_t \}$ is a sequence of mean-zero random variables. The least squares estimator is found by minimizing:
>   $$\sum_{t=1}^{T} [y_t-f(x_t,\beta)]^2$$
>   with respect to $\beta$. Use a first order Taylor series expansion of $f$ to derive an algorithm for the estimation of $\beta$ where $\beta$ is scalar.
>
> Suppose that $\beta = (\beta_1,\beta_2)$. Describe the estimator now.

The algorithm the question refers to is, I beleive, Newton's Method. This method (to find a maximum or minimum) involves iterating, for some function $f(x)$, the following

$$x_n=x_{n-1}-\frac{f'(x_n)}{f''(x_n)}$$

where the initial value $x_0$ is "close" to the maximizing or minimum value of $x$. I am unsure how to apply this to the given optimization problem. I know how to use the method to estimate a max or min for a single variable function, but not with the given $f(x_t,\beta)$ and in the context of estimating least squares. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe the theory section on nonlinear least squares on Wikipedia would be of interest. There's some stuff about Taylor expansions in a least squares setting there. Maybe also the Gauss-Newton algorithm would be of interest. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_least_squares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to minimize a function
$$f:\ {\bf x}\to f({\bf x})\in{\mathbb R}\qquad({\bf x}\in\Omega)$$
and you know beforehand that this minimum is taken at an interior point ${\bf q}\in\Omega$ then this point ${\bf q}$ is necessarily a solution of the equation
$${\bf g}({\bf x}):=\nabla f({\bf x})={\bf 0}\ .\tag{1}$$
When this equation cannot be solved explicitly we can use Newton's method to find  approximate solutions. Start with a reasonable approximation ${\bf p}\in\Omega$. Then $|{\bf g}({\bf p})|$ will be quite small to begin with. For corrections ${\bf X}$ with $|{\bf X}|\ll1$ applied to ${\bf p}$ we have
$${\bf g}({\bf p}+{\bf X})\doteq {\bf g}({\bf p})+d{\bf g}({\bf p}).{\bf X}\tag{2}$$(this is just the idea of derivative). Now we choose ${\bf X}$ such that the right side of $(2)$ becomes ${\bf 0}$. It turns out that in this way $|{\bf g}({\bf p}+{\bf X})|$ will be *essentially* smaller than $|{\bf g}({\bf p})|$. This amounts to putting
$${\bf X}=-\bigl(d{\bf g}({\bf p})\bigr)^{-1}.{\bf g}({\bf p})\ .$$
Then the improved approximation to ${\bf q}$ will be
$${\bf p}':={\bf p}+{\bf X}={\bf p}-\bigl(d{\bf g}({\bf p})\bigr)^{-1}.{\bf g}({\bf p})\ .\tag{3}$$
This procedure can be repeated with ${\bf p}'$ as new starting point.

The main work involved in a Newton step is computing the matrix $\bigl(d{\bf g}({\bf p})\bigr)^{-1}$.
When ${\bf g}$ is given by $(1)$ then its components are $g_i({\bf x})={\partial f\over\partial x_i}({\bf x})$. Therefore the Jacobian matrix $A$ of ${\bf g}$ at ${\bf p}$ is given by
$$a_{ik}:={\partial g_i\over\partial x_k}\biggr|_{{\bf x}={\bf p}}={\partial^2 f\over\partial x_i x_k}\biggr|_{{\bf x}={\bf p}}\qquad(1\leq i,\ k\leq n)\ .$$
It's the inverse of this matrix that appears in $(3)$.